# visual studio vb.net go to line short key (Ctrl + G) is not working?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I use to work in C# and use Ctrl + G for go to line but it is not working in vb.net. Can you please. Edit menu > Go to even not show any short key. If I press Ctrl + G it opens immidiate window. Is there any thing I need to do in order to enable go to short key or is it different when working with vb.net ? Please guide me.

Note:I ma working in Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Make sure that ctrl+g is not being used anywhere else. If it is, delete it from those areas:

1. First type in your shortcut
2. If it appears in the "currently used by"
3. then type it into "Show commands containing"
4. Remove it from "Show commands containing"

[image]

Comment: Step 0.  Apply the following... > Visual Studio 6 worked for me on VS 16.x.x

Answer (score 7):

If you go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, you can change shortcut keys to your heart's content.  To set the go to line shortcut key, type in Edit.GoTo in "Show commands containing", then press Ctrl+G in "Press shortcut keys", and click Assign.  You can find out what Ctrl+G is mapped to already (the immediate window, it sounds like) and re-map that to another key first, if you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

The exact same thing happened to me. I am accustomed to programming in C#, and I use all the shortcuts that C# has such as ctrl+G for goto line. Every time I pressed ctrl+G, it would go to the immediate windows. This started when my "new system" was setup for Visual Basic instead of C#. What I did to fix it was Clicked on "TOOLS" -> Options, and under "Environment" I selected "Keybord". The very Top option it says "Apply the following addional keybord mapping scheme:" And currently selected was Visual Basic. So Once I switch it to Visual C# and clicked OK, my ctrl+g worked for the "goto line" and all my original c# commands worked.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

just had the same. Seem ctrl+G and ctrl+Alt+I are both assigned to the immediate window. What i did, was i selected edit.goto Entered ctrl+g, pressed assign, and all was well